# git integration in microsoft developer studio 2017

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, project

I created a 'solution' and then added a project from outside root directory of the solution.    I noticed that this new project is not recognized (or not added) to git when I view in the 'team explorer'.

If I add copy the project under 'root' directory of solution and then add the project, I do see new files in the team explorer.

what is right way to work/setup?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not see your project under the source control because it outside of your local git repository (not only solution). If you'll copy your external project into the solution directory and add it to the solution that's will be right choice.